# Are my if statements written correctly?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
double soilQuality(int x, int y) {
   double typeA, typeB, soilQual;

   if (((x >= 1) && (x <= 20)) && ((y >= 1) && (y <= 20))) {
      typeA = 1 + (sqrt((pow(x - SOILQUALACONST, 2)) + (pow(y - SOILQUALACONST,          2)) * (1.0)));
      typeB = (1 + ((abs(x - SOILQUALBCONST) + abs(y - SOILQUALBCONST))/(2.0)));

      soilQual = (((x + y) % 2) * typeB) + ((1 - ((x + y) % 2)) * typeA);
   }

   if (((x < 1) || (x >20)) || ((y < 1) || (y > 20))) {
      soilQual = -1.0;
   }

   return soilQual;
```

}

Just a few quick questions, if I were creating variable guards that tested whether or not x and y were on the interval [1, 20], would the first if statement be correct? And if x and y aren't on that interval, I return a -1; is my second if statement correct? And last question, is my syntax for returning the value correct? (More specifically, can I return the value at the very end like I have in my code?)

Because for some reason, my outputs are different than my instructor outputs, I've already double checked my formula and it looks fine to me so I was thinking something was wrong in the syntax of my code.

Thanks!

Comment: You could simply code `if (x >= 1 && x <= 20 && y >= 1 && y <= 20)` which is the same, but much more readable.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the advice Basile Starynkevitch!

Comment: The second `if` clause can be changed to else, as all is done

Comment: You should enable all warnings and debugging information (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I've worked with people who believed all those unnecessary parentheses improved readability. That never made any sense to me.

Comment: As per your question answer is YES. Syntax shown for `if` and `return variable` is correct. Difference in output may be because of different value of `typeA` and `typeB`. You should compare each value to get root of issue causing difference.

Comment: Alright! Hmm...I guess something's wrong with my formula then, I'll check again. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Whether or not x and y were on the interval [1, 20]

Yes, correct.

> And if x and y aren't on that interval, I return a -1; is my second if statement correct?

Yes

But you don't need second if, add else with first if:

```
   if (((x >= 1) && (x <= 20)) && ((y >= 1) && (y <= 20))) {
       // both x, and y are in range [1, 20]
   }
   else{
      soilQual = -1.0; 
   }
```

> And last question, is my syntax for returning the value correct?

Yes, correct

> Because for some reason, my outputs are different than my instructor outputs, I've already double checked my formula and it looks fine to me so I was thinking something was wrong in the syntax of my code.

If there is syntax error then code doesn't compiles!

Because you are working with read numbers, read:
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)